# PapaParse not working (returns empty array)

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I am trying to parse a variant of this file (instead of using tab as delimiter I am using a file that has comma as delimiter) https://github.com/materechm/Schizophrenia/blob/master/GWAS.txt

This is my code, but I am getting an empty array and no errors

```
        var csv = Papa.parse('GWAS.csv', {
        delimiter: ",",
        header: true,
        comments: false,
        complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a local file with Papa Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752889/how-can-i-read-a-local-file-with-papa-parse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no data because you have header row enabled, so the first line of the input is the header row (look in the `meta` property for the list of fields found in the header row).

You've supplied only one line of input, literally the string `"GWAS.csv"`, so there is no data.

If you meant to parse a file, you need to either [pass in a File object from the DOM](http://papaparse.com/docs.html#local-files) or [specify `download: true` in the config](http://papaparse.com/docs.html#remote-files) for Papa Parse to interpret the input string as a URL from which to download the input file.

Comment: The "download: true" fixed it for me. Reading a local file.