# How can I read a local file with Papa Parse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, papaparse

How can I read a local file with Papa Parse? I have a file locally called `challanges.csv`, but after many tried I can't parse it with Papa Parse.

```
var data;

Papa.parse('challanges.csv', {
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    data = results.data;
  }
});
```

As far as I know, I'm having problems with opening the csv file as File. How can I do it with javascript?

Comment: replace `'challanges.csv'` to a file that you get from a file input or some drag and drop

Comment: [This article may help](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parsing-local-csv-file-with-javascript-papa-parse/)

Comment: thank you both, it works indeed, but now every time I refresh my browser, I have to upload the file. Isn't there an easier way? @Endless

Comment: if you want to keep the file after refresh then you need to store the file in some storage layer (preferably the indexedDB storage) for this i can recommend: [localForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-setitem)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `File` API suggested by papaparse's docs is meant for browser used.  Assuming that you are running this on node at server side, what works for me is leveraging the [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const papa = require('papaparse');
const file = fs.createReadStream('challenge.csv');
var count = 0; // cache the running count
papa.parse(file, {
    worker: true, // Don't bog down the main thread if its a big file
    step: function(result) {
        // do stuff with result
    },
    complete: function(results, file) {
        console.log('parsing complete read', count, 'records.'); 
    }
});
```

There may be an easier interface, but so far this works quite well and offer the option of streaming for processing large files.

Comment: This is a beautiful package! It worked well for me just loading csv in the frontend with React.

Comment: @Proghero Did you use the code in Philip's answer to do that or did you roll your own?

Comment: @Casimir I used pretty much the same code as above. Why? Are you having issues?

Comment: I haven't tried the above code yet. It's just that `fs` doesn't work client-side so I was curious how you ported it to frontend React.

Comment: I just passed the file array object that you usually get in React.

Comment: As stated in [PapaParse README](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/README.md#papa-parse-for-node), the worker config option is unavailable on Node

Answer (score 25):

None of these worked for me, I specifically wanted to read in a csv **server side**, and **not client side** (in the borwser). This worked for me.

**async / await**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Papa = require('papaparse');

const csvFilePath = 'data/test.csv'

// Function to read csv which returns a promise so you can do async / await.

const readCSV = async (filePath) => {
  const csvFile = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
  const csvData = csvFile.toString()  
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    Papa.parse(csvData, {
      header: true,
      complete: results => {
        console.log('Complete', results.data.length, 'records.'); 
        resolve(results.data);
      }
    });
  });
};

const test = async () => {
  let parsedData = await readCSV(csvFilePath); 
}

test()
```

If you don't want promise / async, await then you can use this.

**callback**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Papa = require('papaparse');

const csvFilePath = 'data/test.csv'

const file = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath);

var csvData=[];
Papa.parse(file, {
  header: true,
  step: function(result) {
    csvData.push(result.data)
  },
  complete: function(results, file) {
    console.log('Complete', csvData.length, 'records.'); 
  }
});
```

---

Note `header: true` is an option on the config, see docs for other options

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. Async/Await is way to go.

Comment: Calling `readFileSync(filePath)` is a performance killer. Will block the entire application while it is reading. Worse yet, it's already in an async funciton...

Answer (score 9):

You need to add one more line in your config: `download: true,`.

```
var data;

Papa.parse('../challanges.csv', {
  header: true,
  download: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    data = results.data;
  }
});
```

Update: with this answer you dont need a FILE OBject. You can pass the filename and papa parse will "download" it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but got `...\node_modules\papaparse\papaparse.js:591 
 ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined` error. I'm using Papa Parse v.4.5.

Comment: @user1330974 look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644080/xmlhttprequest-is-not-defined-papa-parse

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
1: FE: Angular 10, NPM install ngx-papaparse
Then import in the component

```
import { Papa } from "ngx-papaparse";
```

2: one input with type file only accept csv file on FE

```
 <input type="file" id="csv-file" accept=".csv" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

3: one button to read CSV file

4: we get the file data from the onFileSelected function

```
    const files = event.target.files;
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;
    this.selectedFile = files[0] as File;
```

5: call read CSV file function

```
  this.papa.parse(this.selectedFile, {
        delimiter: ",",
        newline: "",
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: (result) => {
          this.fileData= result.data;
        }
      });
```

6: you should get the object fileData
Tips: check the papaparse documentation to see what configuration you need.
https://www.papaparse.com/
eg:   header: true --> means you will get the headers in the result object

Answer (score -2):

This is to reiterate that the best answer is Murat Seker's.

All that is necessary is to add the to the config `download: true` and the local path will be downloaded by Papa Parse. The streaming answer by Philip M. is not the best answer.

```
var data;

Papa.parse('challanges.csv', {
  header: true,
  download: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    data = results.data;
  }
});
```

P.S. I do not have enough reputation to comment on Murat Seker's answer. So, I reposted an answer. Any love towards reputation will be appreciated. :-)

Comment: The parameter `download: true` makes accessing to the file as an URL, so it's not reading it locally, instead is trying to download it from a web page. The OP asks specifically about reading a local file.

Comment: This works for local files or web files. This is the code I use to read local files.

Comment: As you can read in the docs (https://www.papaparse.com/docs), if you set `download: true`, will use the path as an URL, and so, will try to download it (even if it's from **localhost**, that's not accessing a local file, it's downloading it from a local web server)

Comment: With all due respect, Alex, regardless of what the documents say, the solution as I provided works. It is exactly what is running in production in our system.

Comment: The solution as provided only works if a web server is running on the local machine. In your answer you do not specify it, and just executing this code without a web server will not work. Of course, also, you will be limited to read documents from the web server directory and will not be accessing the local file system. And the answer is specifically saying that wants to read a local file.

Comment: Where would a string representing a local file read from if not the local file system?

You are technically correct that if the code is running client side the configuration I provide will attempt to read a file from the local file system. That is what the original question was asking.

Comment: From a local or remote web server, which is not the same as the local file system. If you provide the parameter `download: true` it won't even try to read the file system, it will make an HTTP request.

Comment: The OP asks for how to access the local file system, which is implied to be the local file system of the service or the client. The solution I present provides that solution.