# Using PapaParse to Parse a Local File?

Tags: papaparse

Currently, I'm trying to [parse a "local file"](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#local-files) this,

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';

Papa.parse( '../raw/M49/en.csv', {
  header: true,
  delimiter: ',',
  complete: (res) => console.log("COMPLETE", res),
  error: err => console.log("ERROR", err)
} );
```

When I run that code, this is all I get back,

```
{ data: [],
  errors: [],
  meta:
   { delimiter: ',',
     linebreak: '\n',
     aborted: false,
     truncated: false,
     cursor: 17,
     fields: [ '../raw/M49/en.csv' ] }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a local file with Papa Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752889/how-can-i-read-a-local-file-with-papa-parse)

Answer (score 1):

Papa Parse has three modes,

1. [Parse String](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#strings) (Obviously don't want it)
2. [Parse Remote File](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#remote-files) (what you want)
3. [Parse Local File](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#local-files) (misnamed, should be `Parse Web API File Object` -- specific to a "File Object" from the Web API)

These are both in browser-parlance where a "LOCAL FILE" is represented by a [File Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). The option that accepts a path, is to [Parse a Remote File](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#remote-files), this requires setting the unintuitive option,

```
download: true
```

Even worse, running this will return,

```
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```