# How to stream a large CSV file on server-side using PapaParse without Node.js?

Tags: javascript, browser, streaming, papaparse

I would like to read a large, local CSV file in chunks using Papa parse in JavaScript, so that the application doesn't get stuck while the file is read. By "local" I mean that the file is on the server-side, accessible to javascript (it's not coming from the user's computer). The application *doesn't* use Node.js.

Papa parse documentation suggests this can be done by passing `step` or `chunk` (both not both) to the `parse` function as well as a file object:

```
Papa.parse(file, 
        {worker: true,
         chunk: function(rows) { ... },
         complete: ...))
```

however it does not say what `file` should be. Other answers on here ([How can I read a local file with Papa Parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752889/how-can-i-read-a-local-file-with-papa-parse)) say it should be a streamable file object but all the answers rely on `require('fs')` from node.js, which this application doesn't use.

Is there a way to read a local (server-side) file in chunks using Papaparse in a way that can be run in the browser, *without* needing node.js?

The method I have tried is this:

```
$.get("./file.csv", function(contents) { 
   // pass contents of file to Papa.parse
   Papa.parse(contents,  {chunk: ...});
});
```

however, since the contents of the csv file are passed as a string to Papa.parse, the browser does become slow and unresponsive when it's running presumably because loading the string into memory is slow. how can I make it so that it's actually streaming from the file object? thanks.